# Check selected option after button click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to pop up an alert when someone clicks on the button. "Please select the size".
I want to check if the size is selected and if so, the button will be work, otherwise show an alert.

Here is my function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function SelectSize() {
    if ($('#SelectSize').is(':selected')) {  
    }
    else {
      alert('Please Select Size');
      return false; 
    }
  }
</script>
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<select name="size"
        id="selectSize"
        class="form-control form-control-select"
        id="group_1"
        style="display:block;">
  <option value="">Select Size</option>
 @foreach($landing->attributes as $size)
  <option value="{{$landing->id}}-{{$size->size}}">{{$size->size}}</option>
 @endforeach
</select>
```

Now:

```
<button type="submit"
        class="btn btn-primary"
        id="cartButton"
        style="background-color:#FF6A13; border: none; display:block;"
        onclick="return SelectSize();">
  <p>
    <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
    Add to cart
  </p>
</button>
```

Comment: Also: Your select has a double *id* attribute!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, note that, you are using two ids in the `select` element. Besides that, the selector inside your function is typographically incorrect.

Now, understanding the selector, `#selectSize` is your `select` element, and to find out the select option, you have to use `option:selected` where `:selected` is a filter for finding selected option. Rest would be easy to understand, I believe.

Using `trim()` saves from the trouble in case the value consists of only white-spaces.

```
function SelectSize() {
  if ($('#selectSize option:selected').val().trim()) {
    //your code
  } else {
    alert('Please Select Size');
    return false; 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your if condition is not right.Here's the code for condition that should work.

```
if($( "#SelectSize option:selected" ).val() !== ""){
    //do your stuff here
}
```